# how to find min value with out count zero in php?

Tags: php, function

i want to find min value with out count zero form min() function in php, but it get me with zero, how can I find out with out zero?

```
     $a = 0; $b = 3; $c= 4, $d = 8;
     $minvalue = min($a,$b,$c,$d);
```

the expected result which I want is to be 3,
but it gives me zero,

how can i neglect zero, i want a result with out zero,
please help me to do this. thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this

```
function ownMin($value)
    {
    return min(array_filter(func_get_args()));
    }
$a = 0; $b = 3; $c= 4; $d = 8;
echo ownMin($a,$b,$c,$d); // 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function my_min(){
   $excludes = array(0); // anything, that should be filtered out.
   $values   = array_diff(func_get_args(), $excludes);

   return min($values);
}

var_dump(my_min(12, 0, 15, 0, 18));
```

Shows:

```
int(12)
```

Take a look at [`array_diff()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) and [`func_get_args()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php).

Comment: This will be useful when you have to exclude other numbers.

Comment: @CertaiN Yeah, I thats the reason I'm post it, regardless of "voted" answer.

Comment: @CORRUPT, do not forget extra argument for array_filter : )

Comment: @sectus there is no `array_filter()` in my code. Am I missing point? What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function nonzero($a){ 
   return ($a > 0); 
} 

min(array_filter($yournumbers,"nonzero"));
```

Answer (score 0):

write you function :

```
function myMin()
{
$numargs = func_num_args();


$arg_list = func_get_args();
$min = PHP_INT_MAX ; 
for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
    if($arg_list[$i] != 0 && $arg_list[$i] < $min)
     {
          $min = Arg_list[$i];
     }
}
return $min;
}
```

call : mymin(0,1,2,3,5)  => 1